# LC3 assembly failed (pass 2)

Tags: assembly, lc3

I have tried to implement subroutines, which I am not sure about how to implement in assembly, but the compiler is failing. The problem seems to disappear if I remove the .BLKW command.

```
.ORIG x3000

JSR SUBROUTINE

HALt


SUBROUTINE
            ST R0, SAVE
            AND R0, R0, #0
            ADD R0, R0, #5
RET
SAVE  .BLKW 1

.END
```

Comment: Works fine here. Make sure you posted the exact code. _"0 errors found in second pass."_ I use v0.12.

Comment: I posted the exact code, the problem seems to disappear if I use .BLKW #1 instead, but the command does not seem to work anymore. I use v1.0.6

Comment: Tested with 1.0.6, can confirm the error but it does seem to work with `#1`. What problem do you have with that?

Comment: Tested a bit more, it looks to be working properly with #1, but for good measure I changed version. Thank you!